# Does Google Drive Web Hosting work privately on Google Apps Accounts

Tags: google-drive-api, clickonce

**Use Case**

I use Google Drive quite heavily in my organisation (Through Google Apps) to collaborate with different teams on documents etc. 
I saw that Google Drive now allows you to host web content directly on it. We have recently made a small .NET application that we need to host locally for our test teams to pick up. Its a slightly different use case, but to keep all our content in one place, I would like to try to host the Click Once Installer completely on Drive, along with the Publish.htm for providing the latest version at all times to our test teams and others. I have limited experience with ClickOnce Deployment in .NET, but have done this in the past on hard drives and Servers.

**Restrictions**

One limitation is that we obviously do not want to make this public, as described in most of the tutorials I found online for this [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T56eZ1lg2oE) and [here](http://css.dzone.com/articles/using-google-drive-web-host). I wouldn't mind keeping it public within my organisation, so anyone with a link could visit this and download the application (This helps us provide it to people in our organisation with no access to development servers etc. in the future).

**2 Key things I need to understand:**

- Does Hosting work locally within an Organisation on Drive (or is this something in the pipeline for Drive SDK). If yes, how is this process different from hosting using public.
- How do I generate the link for a ClickOnce publish.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Publishing works differently from sharing and you cannot restrict access to published files or folders. Sharing lets you restrict access to your file but you cannot easily make direct access to the file which might not be good solution for your use case.

If you really want to use Drive to privately host files, use Google Drive SDK. Here is [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-cs) of how to start C# project. Then, share your file across your organization and use Files.get() to retrieve downloadUrl of the file and then download the content directly. All sample code of getting downloadURL and its content is available in C# in the [following documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get).